# How to test that method gets called with a mix of arguments and keyword arguments in rspec?

Tags: rspec, mocking

I have a method that gets called like this:

```
post_signup(user,
            "fb signup completed",
            app_context: current_app_id,
            description: "Automatically Populated Via #{current_app_id}")
```

The arguments are a mix of values and keyword arguments. The one that I care about in the test is app_context. I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
it "should log an event with an app_context" do
        expect(controller).to receive(:post_signup).with(hash_including(app_context: current_app_id))

        subject
      end
```

and

```
it "should log an event with an app_context" do
        expect(controller).to receive(:post_signup).with(current_app_id, any_args)

        subject
      end
```

What can a man do?

Comment: Do not despair good citizen, the magic of `hash_including` will still save you! http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers#hash_including-instance_method

Comment: just noticing you actually tried that...  :D
but it looks like you tried it as the first argument... but the hash is the second argument so you'd need something like: `expect(controller).to receive(:post_signup).with(anything, hash_including(app_context: current_app_id))` so the `anything` matches the first argument (which is `user`) and the hash_including is then used on the rest of it (which is the hash...)

Comment: Make this the answer @TarynEast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not despair good citizen, the magic of `hash_including` will still save you!

It looks like you tried it as the first argument, but the hash is actually the second argument to your `post_signup` method. The first argument is `user`.

So to make a working `expect` you'd need something like:

```
expect(controller).to receive(:post_signup).with(anything, hash_including(app_context: current_app_id))
```

so the anything matches `user` and the `hash_including` is then used on the rest of it...

Comment: more importantly, is this the sign of a brittle test? One that is too specific for its own good? Should I bet testing the location of arguments in a method call?

Comment: I don't think so... though you could make it all a hash and use `:user => user` and then there'd just be one argument :D